# What's the default Hex Color of the Holo.Light.DarkActionBar ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I've got a toolbar at the bottom of my layout which I would like to be the same color as the action bar. I'm using the Holo Light with dark action bar theme, what is the hex code for this color? Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The action bar's background hex value in the `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` theme is **#222222**. I picked it from the the image that is used as the action bar background:

> [image]
>
> <sdk>/platforms/android-17/data/res/drawable-xhdpi/ab_solid_dark_holo.9.png

Comment: I just changed the size of the image :) Your answer is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

The dark action bar itself is #030304, and the border beneath it is #33b5e5.

It is also worth noting that, if you want a replica of the action bar on the bottom, it's possible to [use a split action bar on API 14+](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar) through use of `uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`.

Comment: Thanks but this is the Holo dark action bar, I'm looking for the one in the theme Holo.Light.DarkActionBar which is not the same. Where did you find it?

Comment: @Jakob I took a screenshot of my (dark UI) app then opened it in Photoshop and nabbed the color code.

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm been doing too, but the color I get from that just looks a little different than the action bar

Comment: Try taking a screenshot of your app with your custom color put in, and place them side-by-side. Perhaps it's not as different as you think!